# How to animate hover on image appearance?

Tags: css

I have this code. How to animate hover appearance without losing text content? http://codepen.io/ijijjnjnjn/pen/ZLVJQr

```
    <div class="girls-15">
  <div class="kitty">
    <p> TEXT </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sprite-test">
  <div class="kitty">
    <p> TEXT </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .girls-15, .sprite-test
{ display: inline-block; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/YZJiO7b.png') no-repeat; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; }

.girls-15 { background-position: -0px -0px; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
.sprite-test { background-position: -0px -200px; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
p {margin:0; color: red}

.kitty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.kitty:hover {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/6cEsPeM.jpg');
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your CodePen doesn't show any change on hover currently.

Comment: Is this a joke? On hover cat appears.

Comment: I want to animate .kitty div.

Comment: No joke, nothing happens in codepen

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgRrpx

It animates the background image using `opacity`, because the `background-image` property cannot be directly animated in CSS. It also uses a bit of jQuery in order to preserve the content of your elements.

Comment: I don't need jQ for this.